# Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in App#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I've been trying to setup my dev environment using Rails v.  6.0.2.1 with webpacker creating a server on port 3035 while having a PostgreSQL database running on 5432. This is all done on windows, btw.

Essentially, I've been running into the issue that whenever I managed to get a steady connection to the database, webpacker appears to fail the compiling of my code and only produces a MissingEntryError. I've previously been able to produce a Manifest.Json file in my public/packs, but it was to my understanding that this file is autogenerated by the plugin.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

webpacker.yml

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .jsx
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

And this is the webpacker error log

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in C:/Users/Bruger/Desktop/hydac-rails/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
):
    18:
    19:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    20:     <%= stylesheet_pack_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload" %>
    21:     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    22:     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'app' %>
    23:     <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'app' %>
    24:     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo|Lato:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:21
```

Based on question from @stwienert

contents of webpack

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
ENV["NODE_ENV"]  ||= "development"

require "pathname"
ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require "bundler/setup"

require "webpacker"
require "webpacker/webpack_runner"

APP_ROOT = File.expand_path("..", __dir__)
Dir.chdir(APP_ROOT) do
  Webpacker::WebpackRunner.run(ARGV)
end
```

Output of npx run webpack

```
C:\Users\Bruger\Desktop\hydac-rails\bin\webpack:3
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
                 ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

And a picture of my javascript/packs folder
[javascript/packs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVx82.png)

Comment: whats the output of ``bin/webpack``? What's the content of ``app/javascript/packs/*``? The manifest will be created when a webpack run is successful. Normally when running without a separate webpack-dev-server, Rails will kick off webpack when reading the ``javascript_pack_tag``.

Comment: @stwienert added necessary documentation to question

Comment: I meant: Whats the output, when you **run** ``./bin/webpack``.

Comment: bin/webpack is a **ruby** executable, it needs to be run directly or via bundle exec, but not through npx. It will call webpack by itself with the correct arguments. The command it will run would be like: : ``./node_modules/.bin/webpack -c config/webpack/development.js``  -- just replace / with \ for windows, though :D

Comment: @stwienert running the bundle exec command with the parameters you gave me delivers this output:

https://imgur.com/LBQZ7Qf

Comment: That's what I thought: Webpack cannot run successfully, ergo there is no manifest.json and thus the error. You need to investigate on how to configure the webpack correctely for your use case. Make sure which Webpacker version you are using: Webpack's Readme is now on the newest Webpacker6.beta, but you might have a different version, like Webpacker 5.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

```
  yarn add @rails/webpacker
  bundle update webpacker
```

Method 2:

```
  RAILS_ENV={environment} bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

Method 3:

```
  rm -rf bin/webpack*
  RAILS_ENV={environment} bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
```

For more info refer this [link](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1494#issuecomment-388305305)

Comment: Have you refer the above link ? It contains some other answers also

Comment: running windows I am unable to duplicate these commands in my terminal with any effect.